# Discrete wavelet decomposition over detail coefficients

Tags: discrete-wavelet-transform, pywavelets

per my understanding, if we take a 3-level discrete wavelet decomposition (DWT) over a 1-D signal with sampling rate $F_s$, we will get a series of detail and approximation coefficients, ex: [cA3, cD3, cD2, cD1] (use pywavelet outputs as example), where cD1 corresponds to the frequency band $[F_s/4, F_s/2]$, cD2 corresponds to the frequency band $[F_s/8, F_s/4]$, cD3 corresponds to $[F_s/16, F_s/8]$, and cA3 corresponds to $[0, F_s/16]$.

I am wondering

1. Can we take DWT over the detail coefficients, ex: cD3, and get the detail and approximation coefficients (say, [cD3_cA1, cD3_cD1])?
2. What are cD3_cA1's and cD3_cD1's corresponding frequency bands? Will they be $[0, F_s/32]$ and $[F_s/32, F_s/16]$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Indeed, that will be called a wavelet packet.
2. No, you will split the cD3 band in two equal parts: $[Fs/16,3Fs/32]$  and $[3Fs/32,Fs/8]$ as you mentioned.

Warning though, the frequency bin you indicate are only indicative, there exists leakage in the neighboring bands and this gets worse as you pile wavelet packet levels. Only the case of the [Shannon-Nyquist or sinc wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_wavelet) is supposed to offer correct binning, but in practice, its slow decay generates other border artifacts on signals with short support.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I know the frequency ranges can only be rough since the wavelets are not perfect bandpass filters. For question 2, do you mean that cD3_cA1's and cD3_cD1's corresponding frequency bands are (roughly) $[F_s/16, 3F_s/32]$ and $[3F_s/32, F_s/8]$?

Comment: Indeed. Except for the Shannon-Nyquist wavelet, the integer dyadic bins are not precise. I have edited the answer accordingly with details